# Is there a swedish language pack for EPiServer Relate+ 2.0?

Tags: episerver-6, relate

I've looked everywhere, I can't find any extra languages for Relate+

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included a link to a gist with the translation

[RelatePlusSV.xml](https://gist.github.com/1037398)